# MongoDB - Should I split Messages collection in more than 1?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, chat

I have a `Message` collection which looks something like this;

```
Message {
    userId,
    text,
    chatRoomId
}
```

The collection now has over 5M documents and it grows fast. Is there a point where I should split the collection in 2? Like `Message_1` & `Message_2`...

Note that the collection is indexed and it's quite fast. I'm just worried if it becomes an issue in the future where there could be 10 or 20 million messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split it into two collections, then how will search? First search in the collection1 and then in collection2 and then merge?

Not a good idea. Check [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) instead. Its same as splitting with the difference that everything is managed by MongoDB and both collections resides on differnet servers (Use it only if you are sure you will always have a key (say userId, termed as shard key) in all your searches.)

Also you don't need sharding or splitting even for 1 billion records. MongoDB is quite efficient (and also most other databases as well). 10-20 million records are not a big number provided that you are searching only on indexed fields and not using some text search (like contains word) on the text field

Comment: I am querying on indexed fields! The find query is very efficient, but I was skeptical on whether that amount of data could potentially affect the responsiveness of the db in general...